# Tables not coming in center of div

Tags: javascript, html-table

I am trying to create 3 tables by Javascript inside a div and then put them inside HTML of an existing div. Please find the entire code here:

https://jsfiddle.net/s78n3dfe/

HTML File

```
<div id = "tldr">
</div>
```

Javascript File

```
map1 = [["label1", 30], ["label2", 70]];
total1 = 100;
title1 = "dasdas";
var table1 = createTable(map1, total1, title1);
var table2 = createTable(map1, total1, title1);
var table3 = createTable(map1, total1, title1);

var divNode = document.createElement('div');
divNode.setAttribute("id", "labelInfo");
divNode.appendChild(table1);
  divNode.appendChild(table3);
  divNode.appendChild(table2);

  var tldr = document.getElementById('tldr');
  tldr.appendChild(divNode);

function createTable(map, total, title) {
  var table = document.createElement('table');
    table.setAttribute("class", "table");
    table.classList.add("table-striped");
    // table.setAttribute("class", "table-striped");
    table.setAttribute("style", "display: inline-block; width:33%;");

    var caption = table.createCaption();
    caption.setAttribute("style", "text-align: center;")
    caption.innerHTML = title.toString().bold();

    var header = table.createTHead();
    var firstRow = header.insertRow(0);
    var header1 = firstRow.insertCell(0);
    var header2 = firstRow.insertCell(1);

    header1.innerHTML = "Label".bold();
    header2.innerHTML = "Allocation".bold();

    var tblBody1 = document.createElement("tbody");
    tblBody1.setAttribute('class', 'percentageBody');
    tblBody1.setAttribute('style', 'display:block; border-top: 0px;');
    table.appendChild(tblBody1);

    for(label in map) {
      var row = document.createElement("tr");
      var labelCell = row.insertCell(0);
      var percentCell = row.insertCell(1);

      labelCell.innerHTML = map[label][0].bold();
      percentCell.innerHTML = map[label][1].toString().concat(" %");

      tblBody1.appendChild(row);
    }

    var tblBody2 = document.createElement("tbody");
    tblBody2.setAttribute('class', 'valueBody');
    tblBody2.setAttribute('style', 'display:none; border-top: 0px;');
    table.appendChild(tblBody2);

    for(label in map) {
      var row = document.createElement("tr");
      var labelCell = row.insertCell(0);
      var percentCell = row.insertCell(1);

      labelCell.innerHTML = (map[label][0]).bold();
      percentCell.innerHTML = (map[label][1]/100 * total).toFixed(0).toString();

      tblBody2.appendChild(row);
    }

    return table;
}
```

The problem I am facing is that tables are coming towards the left side of the div and not coming in the center. How can I make them come in the center?

Comment: Your code is not working in https://jsfiddle.net/1Ljmtons/13/ - Display error: "[object HTMLDivElement]"

Comment: this is a css related issue but you are not showing us what is causing the issue. What you show is what is working

Comment: @kiranmalvi I have fixed it. Can u check now? I have put new fiddle endpoint.

Comment: @LelioFaieta I have shown the issue in the output like tables are all coming towards left of the div

Comment: where is your css? it's through css that you determine the layout of your page. This is what is causing the issue. Not the js that build the tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check below Code:

Remove Inline-block from table's CSS:

[image]